# Выбрать из таблицы цену по названию товара

Tags: excel

Использую формулу для вывода цены:

```
=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(B2=Цены!$A$3);Цены!$B$3;
ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(B2=Цены!$A$4);Цены!$B$4;
ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(B2=Цены!$A$5);Цены!$B$5;
ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(B2=Цены!$A$6);Цены!$B$6;
ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(B2=Цены!$A$7);Цены!$B$7;
ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(B2=Цены!$A$8);Цены!$B$8))))))
```

Вообщем у меня формула фиксированная, если я например в таблице добавлю еще что-то, то формулу придется редактировать самому вручную, как сделать так, чтобы при добавлении нового обьекта в таблице, формула сама менялась?
На первой картинке - таблица в листе 1, тут как раз мне потребуется что-то добавить, например 150пуль по цене 5000руб
На второй картинке - таблица в листе 2, в нем все и происходит
На третей картинке - показан выпадающий список в листе 1, этот список связан с той таблицей которая в листе 2. Но формула при этом не меняется
На четвертой картинке показана более понятная формула, не в одной строке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эту функцию, наверное, не знают только те, кто сегодня открыл для себя `Excel`. Одна из самых применяемых наряду с `ЕСЛИ`, `ИЛИ`, `И` Даже выражение расхожее есть - "отвэпээрить" :)

```
=ВПР(B2;Цены!$A$3:$B$150;2;)
```